# Request parameter error at POST - Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, http-post, filesize

This error occurs every time when the page tries to submit a 2MB, or greater, file. But the parameters is in the POST! I've checked on Chrome dev tools.
Does anyone know this error?
**Springboot 2.0.3.RELEASE**

> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
> Required String parameter 'certThumb' is not present  at
> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:204)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:112)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:57)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:54)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:74)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:77)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:86)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at
> org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AbstractAuthenticatedActionsValve.java:67)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
> at
> org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:181)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you mention your classes and code? Although I see the following error `Required String parameter 'certThumb' is not present at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it!.
The problem was on the tomcat.max-http-post-size. When I posted a large file then Spring Boot crashed.

I need to increase the maximum Post size in the TOMCAT.